# How to move all files of subdirectories to another directory

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

My files have the following structure:

```
11
--11a
-----a.jpg
-----b.jpg
-----....
--11b
-----d.jpg
-----g.jpg
...
```

I want to have **all the .jpg files in one folder**:

```
11
-a.jpg
-b.jpg
-d.jpg
-g.jpg
...
```

Basically I have subfolders with many .jpg files and I want to move all of them to one directory (e.g. parent).

I have tried:
`mv */*.jpg all` but I get `-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long`.

Some posts suggest [xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long) and some other the [find](https://superuser.com/questions/658075/how-do-i-move-files-out-of-nested-subdirectories-into-another-folder-in-ubuntu) solution but unfortunately nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: Are you certain all the file names are unique? How should conflicts be handled if not? I think `find` will give you a solution, but you need to answer these questions before I can suggest a solution.

Comment: Yes the file names are unique so there are no conflicts at all.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/496768/468052) might work for osx as well. It is an elegant gui solution.

Answer (score 5):

If the file names are unique, use:

```
find {base folder}/11 -name "*.jpg" -exec mv {} {base folder}/11/ \;
```

where `{base folder}` is where the directory `11` resides.

This runs the `mv` command on each file in turn: it will be a lot slower than moving all the files in a single `mv` command, but there will be no restrictions on the length of the argument list.

If some of the file names could be in upper case, you can use `-iname` instead of `-name`. You can also add `-n` to make sure you do not overwrite a file which has been moved already (you need to check that your `mv` has this option - if not use `-i`, though this will prompt on conflicts).

You can get rid of any empty directories with:

```
rmdir {base folder}/11/*
```

You will need to investigate any directories that remain after this command.

Comment: How about `find … -exec mv … +`? It should pass multiple paths to `mv`, taking care of the line length though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I'm sceptical: the line length will probably work out the same as in your original `mv` command, and subject to the same limitations.

Comment: Eh, even worse: it won't work at all. Now i see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152723/108618) that `only a <plus-sign> that immediately follows an argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the end of the primary expression.` Still `find {base folder}/11 -name "*.jpg" -exec mv -t {base folder}/11/ {} +` should work (it appears this is exactly the purpose of `-t` option). The downside is the `find` will match already moved files. One can fight it specifying depth, or accept `source and target are the same file` error that should do no harm.

Comment: There is an ordering option on `find` which allows subdirectories to be traversed in such a way that finding the same file in two places should not occur. Another approach is to process the files a directory at a time, instead of a file at a time: this should limit the `mv` parameter length. Use something like `for d in {base folder}/11/; do [ -d "$d" ] && eval mv "$d/*.jpg" {base folder}/11/; done`. This needs to be elaborated, as in this simple form it will generate errors, but it shows the approach. I've just had a gruelling 24 hours, so I can't work out all the niceties at present.

Comment: Works for me, other solutions online did not, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

This should be as easy as "mv */*.your_extension ./"

Comment: If down voters put some comment It will be more easy to trace the issue or update the answer. Thanks.