# rename all jpeg files sequentially in all nested subfolders and move to a new folder

Tags: linux, file-transfer, file-management

My question is similar to this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811336/rename-jpeg-files-sequentially-in-multiple-subfolders

but my folder structure is like this

```
├── mainfolder
|    ├── subfolder1
|    |   ├── 01folder
             |--02folder
                 |--03folder 
                      |--- 0001.jpg
|    |                └── 0002.jpg
                      ...
|    |                └── 0250.jpg
|    |
|    ├── subfolder2
           |── 01folder
                |--02folder
                     |--03folder 
|    |                  ├── 0001.jpg
|    |                  └── 0002.jpg
                         ...
|    |                  └── 0250.jpg
|    |
|    ├── subfolder3
           ├── 01folder
                 |--02folder
                     |--03folder  
|    |                   ├── 0001.jpg
|    |                   └── 0002.jpg
                         ...
|    |                   └── 0250.jpg
…
```

all folders have jpg images numbered from 1 to 250 for a total of 100000 images. I would like to move all the files and rename them before moving them so the folder structure looks like this

```
├── newfolder
|    |--1.jpg
|    |--2.jpg
|    |--3.jpg
...
|    |--100000.jpg
```

I am currently using this

to move all the files from the nested subdirectories to a new directory

```
find ~/mainfolder/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/newfolder/
```

[How do I move files out of nested subdirectories into another folder in ubuntu? (Trying to strip off many subfolders)](https://superuser.com/questions/658075/how-do-i-move-files-out-of-nested-subdirectories-into-another-folder-in-ubuntu)

not sure how to rename them as well though as they will overwrite each other due to having the same name when moving resulting in only 250 files instead of 100000 files.

Comment: Is the order of directories important? Is the order of files important? E.g. `0001.jpg` from `subfolder3` must end up as `501.jpg`; or may not, except all files from `subfolder3` must get consecutive numbers; or they may be "interleaved" in any way. Can there be a gap? like `subfolder10` missing or `subfolder12/0123.jpg` missing? What then? Respective gap in the output numbering? or consecutive numbering no matter what?

Answer (score 2):

With Larry Wall's `rename`/`prename`(*) you can easily "flatten" the structure:

```
cd mainfolder
rename -n 's:/:-:g' */*/*.jpg
```

This will move `subfolder1/0001.jpg` to `subfolder1-0001.jpg` (in `mainfolder`) because `rename` edits the whole input path and then does the equivalent of `mv` using source and edited names.

- `g` in the edit means to replace all occurrences, useful if you have more than one level of subdirectories.
- `-n` just shows what it would do without doing anything
- remove or replace by `-v` for the actual action.
- by default no overwrite can happen (you need a `-f`) but normally since this includes subdirectories in the names you shouldn't have name clashes anyway.
- once everything is in `mainfolder`, it is easy to do a bulk move elsewhere if needed.
- if the files are in various levels of nesting, use `shopt -s globstar` and use `**` to denote all levels:

  ```
  rename s:/:-:g **/*.jpg
  ```

For instance:

Starting with

```
.
├── sub1
│   ├── subsub1
│   │   ├── 001.jpg
│   │   ├── 002.jpg
│   │   └── 003.jpg
│   └── subsub2
│       ├── 001.jpg
│       ├── 002.jpg
│       └── 003.jpg
└── sub2
    ├── subsub1
    │   ├── 001.jpg
    │   ├── 002.jpg
    │   └── 003.jpg
    └── subsub2
        ├── 001.jpg
        ├── 002.jpg
        └── 003.jpg
```

Execute:

```
rename s:/:-:g */*/*.jpg
```

This results in:

```
.
├── sub1
│   ├── subsub1
│   └── subsub2
├── sub1-subsub1-001.jpg
├── sub1-subsub1-002.jpg
├── sub1-subsub1-003.jpg
├── sub1-subsub2-001.jpg
├── sub1-subsub2-002.jpg
├── sub1-subsub2-003.jpg
├── sub2
│   ├── subsub1
│   └── subsub2
├── sub2-subsub1-001.jpg
├── sub2-subsub1-002.jpg
├── sub2-subsub1-003.jpg
├── sub2-subsub2-001.jpg
├── sub2-subsub2-002.jpg
└── sub2-subsub2-003.jpg
```

And you can get rid of the subdirectories using

```
rm -r sub*/
```

(final slash is important! it restricts the match to directories)

So finally:

```
.
├── sub1-subsub1-001.jpg
├── sub1-subsub1-002.jpg
├── sub1-subsub1-003.jpg
├── sub1-subsub2-001.jpg
├── sub1-subsub2-002.jpg
├── sub1-subsub2-003.jpg
├── sub2-subsub1-001.jpg
├── sub2-subsub1-002.jpg
├── sub2-subsub1-003.jpg
├── sub2-subsub2-001.jpg
├── sub2-subsub2-002.jpg
└── sub2-subsub2-003.jpg
```

If you have a huge collection of files, you cannot process in one call because the file expansion of **/*.jpg will generate a list which is too long (/bin/sh: 1: rename: Argument list too long`). So you have to split the work, for instance by calling rename once by directory:

```
shopt -s globstar 
for d in **/; do rename s:/:-:g "$d"*.jpg; done
```

(the `/` in '**/' is important, it restricts the expansion to directories)

If you still  get the `Argument list too long` message then you have a directory with very many files :) You just have to find a way to split the work, for instance:

```
for f in path/to/hugedir/A*;jpg; do rename s:/:-:g "$d"*.jpg; done
for f in path/to/hugedir/B*;jpg; do rename s:/:-:g "$d"*.jpg; done
[... etc ...]
```

If this is still too big and or you want to be blunt, you can also call rename once for each file:

```
shopt -s globstar 
for f in **/*.jpg; do rename s:/:-:g "$f"; done
```

(this will work because here the expansion of "**/*.jpg" is just a variable in your shell, and not the list of arguments to a command).

PS: `bash` assumed here, if you are putting this in a script, make sure the "shebang" is `/bin/bash`, on some systems `sh` is a lightweight shell (`dash`) that doesn't support `globstar`.

(*) name varies depending on distro, `rename` for Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives, and IIRC `prename` on RedHat and derivatives.

Comment: thanks i am getting Can't rename */*.jpg *-*.jpg: No such file or directory, not the actually file would be nested farther like this /subdir/01/01/0001.jpg

Comment: In you post you have one level of subdirectories, but now you have two? Then see edited answer...

Comment: yes I simplied it but thats why I wrote nested dir in the title and gave example of moving nested dir, sorry, also /bin/sh: 1: rename: Argument list too long

Comment: Check what you `rename` variant is, there is another command of the  same name. The author in `man rename` should be Larry Wall. The executable is actually a perl script. It is possibly called prename on your system (if already installed).

Comment: I think it is rename as it shows the usage instructions when I do rename --help Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr
    [ files ]

Comment: Looks like the right `rename`, so what exact rename command did you use? What are the perlexpr and how did you specify the files?

Comment: I am using this rename s:/:-:g */*/*/*.jpg since the dir structure is main/sub/01/01/0001.jpg

Comment: use your filespec with `ls` to see what you are passing to `rename`. In practice, no need for leading slash... and you forgot an asterisk for the file names. I think  you need `rename s:/:-:g */*/*/*.jpg`. And don't forget that your CWD should be `mainfolder`.

Comment: I tried `rename s:/:-:g */*/*/*.jpg` still getting `/bin/sh: 1: rename: Argument list too long` I am in the mainfolder

Comment: OK, see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

rename

```
import os


def main():
    path = "/path/"
    count = 1

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for i in files:
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, i), os.path.join(root, "changed" + str(count) + ".jpg"))
            count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and

then move to parent directory

```
find /main/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /dest/
```