# Move files from subdirectories to new folder recursively (all files [jpg/png/...] apart from jsons)

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I have a folder Google Photos. This is from a google photos takeout. The way the takeout works is there are multiple folders with date names

```
➜  ~/Google Photos => tree |head -n 20     
.
├── 1979-12-31
│   ├── icon-24x24.png
│   ├── icon-24x24.png.json
│   ├── icon_local_color.png
│   ├── icon_local_color.png.json
│   ├── metadata.json
│   ├── viewer-14.png
│   ├── viewer-14.png.json
│   ├── viewer-28.png
│   └── viewer-28.png.json
├── 2001-07-24
│   ├── heic0109a.jpg
│   ├── heic0109a.jpg.json
│   └── metadata.json
├── 2003-01-06
│   ├── ASPdotNET_logo.jpg
│   ├── ASPdotNET_logo.jpg.json
│   ├── darkBlue_GRAD.jpg
│   ├── darkBlue_GRAD.jpg.json
```

I would like to move all the files which do not end in json to a new folder called `./all_photos`. The issue is that I may have two files with the same name in folders.

For example in the folder `1979-12-31` I may have a file called `a.jpg` and in the folder `2001-07-24` I may also have another file called `a.jpg`. Solutions I have looked at move the files but overwrite or skip if there is a potential overwrite. I would like to change the filenames as shown: `1979-12-31_a.jpg` and `2001-07-24_a.jpg`. This will ensure there are no files with the same name and therefore no overwriting.

I am on a Linux server and I imagine the best way to do this would be through Linux find command but I am unsure of the exact commands so would like a helping hand.

Comment: You might want to rename all the generic .jpg files first, using the (hopefully) embedded exif data like date taken. Then you can just copy everything without worrying about collisions

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1422613/670091

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rename all jpeg files sequentially in all nested subfolders and move to a new folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1422563/rename-all-jpeg-files-sequentially-in-all-nested-subfolders-and-move-to-a-new-fo)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help but I think my question is different as I wish to move all files whose file extension is not json whereas the solution suggested only works for one filetype at a time

Comment: In bash you can use negative matching:  `!(*.json)`

Comment: @xenoid I tried this but I keep getting errors https://imgur.com/a/GZoPimM

I think I might have the wrong rename program (I'm on debian 9). Is there any solution which does not involve usage of another program, maybe just standard linux command line?

Comment: You also need `shopt -s extglob` (didn't mention it because it is usually on by default thse days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script I wrote to solve the problem. Probably not the most efficient way but if there is a more efficient way please let me know. Takes one parameter - the folder name for which you would like to apply the script. In the example above I would run `./script.sh Google\ Photos`. Works for 2 levels of subfolders.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for x in `ls $1` 
do
    for y in $1/$x/!(*.json)
    do
        a=${y#"$1/$x/"}
        mv $y "$1/$x-$a"
    done
done
```